# Вывод данных из Sqlite3 python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Как сделать чтобы выводились полные данные а не последние которые записаны в БД
например сейчас в бд записи

ID  File

1   23

2   333

3   55

ну и как итог он у меня выводит только последнее значение 55

```
def existing():
conn = sqlite3.connect('bd/to.db')
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT File from OT")
for j in cursor:
    value = StringVar()
    valueChosen = ttk.Combobox(root, width=12, textvariable=value, state='readonly')
    print(len(j))

    valueChosen['values'] = (j)

    valueChosen.place(x=300,y=500)
    valueChosen.current(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать чтобы значение выводились строчно вместо обозначения массива нужно написать **results = cursor.fetchall()**

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('bd/to.db')
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT File from OT")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    value = StringVar()
    valueChosen = ttk.Combobox(root, width=12, textvariable=value, state='readonly')
    valueChosen['values'] = (results)
    valueChosen.place(x=300,y=500)
    valueChosen.current(0)
```